# Grafana / Prometheus : Detect Time of Spike Back to Zero

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a pattern of load I am monitoring in Grafana / Prometheus, that looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is to track the time of day at which the spike comes back down to zero.

The spike typically does not reoccur within a 24 hour period. Can you suggest how this data point could be captured in this scenario?

Looking to trigger an alarm if the zero point doesn't occur before a given time of day, as well as track the zero time day over day historically.

Comment: Please clarify, you intend to use it only as an alert? And let me re-iterate: you want alert to happen, if at 15:00 (for example), there were no spikes withing last N hours, or of it is still >0?

Comment: Not [currently] looking for an alert. Rather, I am looking to record that time as a metric. Say.... the number of minutes into the current day when the value returns to zero after a spike exceeding 500,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get **timestamp** of point in time as you described with query like this:

```
timestamp(my_metric == 0) 
 and my_metric offset 1m > 0
 and max_over_time(my_metric[8h])>500000
```

It checks, that current value is 0. One minute ago value bigger then 0. And over last 8 hours value was more than 500.000.

If all conditions are met, timestamp is returned. Otherwise, nothing is returned.

Be sure to change `1m` used in offset, to your evaluation `evaluation_interval`.

If you'll create recording rule with such expression, recorded metric will have values only when conditions are met. If you want to use it's value over extended period of time (for example on the panel), you'll need to use query like this:

```
last_over_time(last_spike:my_metric:timestamp[1w])
```

---

I don't now clear way to convert timestamp to number of seconds since last midnight. Most likely simple `timestamp(my_metric == 0) % (24*60*60) and ...` should work, but I can't guarantee that there are no nuances regarding time in that case.

If it works, logic about need to use `last_over_time` still stands.